# Error in arff module

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, arff

I am working in `Python 2.7.12` in linux. I have installed the liac-arff and arff modules for the machine. The following line throws an error.

```
arff_frame = arff.load(
        open(filename, 'r'), encode_nominal=encode_nominal, return_type=arff.DENSE)
```

The error is, `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DENSE'`
Any suggestions about how to address this error?

Comment: Your problem is this: `return_type=arff.DENSE`. What do you think it does?

Comment: @BoarGules Here is the explanation from documentation.
`return_type – determines the data structure used to store the dataset. Can be one of arff.DENSE, arff.COO and arff.LOD`
For reference, this same statement worked for me in Windows Anaconda Python 3 distribution and somehow doesn't work on the linux machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your script file is not named `arff.py`. It prevents import of `arff` module you installed.

Also make sure there's no `arff.pyc` remained.

**UPDATE**

Make sure that you installed `liac-arff` (not `arff`) package.

```
>>> import arff
>>> arff.DENSE
0
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! These were already taken care of!

Comment: Worked like a charm!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `liac-arff` at https://pythonhosted.org/liac-arff/ gives the signature of the function as

```
arff.load(fp, encode_nominal=False, return_type=0)
```

It looks like you have this version in your Python 2 environment. That is the version you get if you do `pip install arff`.